# rails 3 formtastic align radio buttons horizontally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

How do I get radio buttons to align horizontally?
for example:

```
<%= f.input :rating, :as => :radio, :collection => [["1", 1], ["2", 2], ["3", 3]] %>
```

is displayed as,

rating

[ ] 1

[ ] 2

[ ] 3

I want:

rating [ ] 1 [ ] 2 [ ] 3

Update: fixed by adding

```
.formtastic fieldset > ol >li.radio fieldset ol li {
  margin:0.1em 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

to active_admin.css.scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the formtastic wiki on [css customization](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/6.1-Customize%3a-CSS#wiki-Example) and [here](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/pull/516), it seems that css is the way to do it.